# Python class function not returning variable

Tags: python, mechanize

I think I may be overlooking something simple.   I have a class with a constructor defined.  In one of the functions I make a call to an api an store the response in a variable.  I'd like to return that variable. kind of like, info = MyClass(),  data = info.somefunctuon().  In my case data always returns None.

here is a snippet of what I have.

```
class SomeAPI(object):

    def __init__(self, br, cj, username, password, logged_in='', api_id='', data=''):
        self.br = br
        self.cj = cj
        self.logged_in = False
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.api_id = api_id
        br.set_cookiejar(self.cj)
        br.set_handle_robots(False)

    def _login_check(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(self):
            if self.log_in():
                f(self)
            else:
                raise MyError('Not Logged In')
        return wrapper

    def log_in(self):
        auth_data = {'cmd': 'auth', 'params': {'username': self.username,
                                               'password': self.password}}
        if not self.logged_in:
            self.br.open('https://someurl.com/auth', dumps(auth_data))

            data = loads(self.br.response().read())
            status = data['response']['status']

            if status == 'OK':
                api_id = data['response']['api_id']
                self.logged_in = True
                self.api_id = api_id
            else:
                raise MyError(status)
        return self.logged_in

    @_login_check
    def campaigns_list(self):
        campaigns_list_data = {'cmd': 'ab_campaigns'}

        raw = self.br.open('https://someurl.com/{}'.format(self.api_id),
                                                    dumps(campaigns_list_data))
        json_resp = raw.read()
        resp = loads(json_resp)
        status = resp['response']['status']

        if status == 'OK':
            data = resp['response']['Ad Campaigns']
            return data
```

when I do:

```
info = SomeAPI(mechanize.Browser(), cookielib.LWPCookieJar(), 'MyName', '12345')
data = info.campaigns_list() 
print data
```

I always get None. I know that I get the data because when i replace return with print I get the expected response. I thought maybe I'd need to define data on the constructor, but then each function of my class would need its own variable defined. I think it would get messy.

Any suggestions please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Probably you access the particular piece of result incorrectly - add the information on what the `print` shows, when you put it instead of `return`.

Comment: What if the status is not "OK"? the value returned by your function would be None in all those cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator `_login_check` calls the function it wraps, but it doesn't return whatever the function returns.

Change:

```
def _login_check(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self):
        if self.log_in():
            f(self)
        else:
            raise MyError('Not Logged In')
    return wrapper
```

to:

```
def _login_check(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self):
        if self.log_in():
            return f(self)
        else:
            raise MyError('Not Logged In')
    return wrapper
```

Comment: good catch! That did the trick.  I knew I was overlooking something. I was trying everything except looking at the decorator I made.  Thanks again